# jQuery endless- animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

i am working on a endless jquery animation, which draws 6 divs and swaps them persition by persition. (better you take a look at the link)
The positions of the divs are held in an array and each cycle, its elements are swaped a position.
The animation is ready and works out, the problem I am having is, that I dont really know how to call it in a endless loop.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/EN55j/8/) is the code to work with.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/EN55j/8/embedded/result/) is the animation to view in fullscreen.

thx for any help;

HTML:

```
<head> </head>

<body>

<style>

div { background-color: #3f3; }

</style>

<div style="position:absolute" class="block-flex-4" id="block-video-4">
ELEMENT1
</div>


<div style="position:absolute" class="block-flex-5 block-flex" id="block-video-5">
ELEMENT2
</div>

<div style="position:absolute" class="block-flex-6 block-flex" id="block-video-6">
ELEMENT3                           
</div>

<div style="position:absolute" class="block-flex-3 block-flex" id="block-video-3">
ELEMENT4                           
</div>

<div style="position:absolute" class="block-flex-2 block-flex" id="block-video-2">
ELEMENT5                           
</div>

<div style="position:absolute" class="block-flex-1 block-flex" id="block-video-1">
ELEMENT6                     
</div>


</body>
```

JS:

```
try{
    var arrayFlexRotation = new Array(
    [110, 93, 38, 119, 1],
    [177, 153, 172, 190, 1],
    [83, 70, 412, 217, 0.35],
    [194, 168, 201, 0, 1],
    [167, 145, 424, 10, 1],
    [141, 123, 553, 175, 0.8]
);

    var doAnim = function(elt, eltWidth, eltHeight, eltLeft, eltTop, eltFontSize){

    jQuery(elt).wait().animate({
    width: eltWidth + "px",
    height: eltHeight + "px",
    left: eltLeft + "px",
    top: eltTop + "px",
    fontSize: eltFontSize + "em"
    }, 5000,null,null);

}

        jQuery.fn.wait = function(time, type) {
        time = time || 500;
        type = type || "fx";
        return this.queue(type, function() {
            var self = this;
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(self).dequeue();
            }, time);
        });
    };


        function runit(){
    var temp = arrayFlexRotation[0];
    arrayFlexRotation[0] = arrayFlexRotation[1];
    arrayFlexRotation[1] = arrayFlexRotation[2];
    arrayFlexRotation[2] = arrayFlexRotation[5];
    arrayFlexRotation[5] = arrayFlexRotation[4];
    arrayFlexRotation[4] = arrayFlexRotation[3];
    arrayFlexRotation[3] = temp;



    //animate position
    for(i=0; i<6; i++)
    {
doAnim(jQuery("#block-video-" + (i+1)), arrayFlexRotation[i][0], arrayFlexRotation[i][3], arrayFlexRotation[i][2], arrayFlexRotation[i][3], arrayFlexRotation[i][4]);
    }


}
runit();
runit();
runit();
//and so on

}
    catch(e)
    {
     alert(e);   
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The animate() function has a complete parameter, *which is A function to call once the animation is complete.* Guess you can just pass your anim function in the complete param so that it continuously calls itself as it finishes each iteration?

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: this is exactly what i was trying at first, but there are 6 animations going at the same time (1 per div move) and _after_ this 6 animations the whole process should restart. so not the animate function should run in a endloss loop, rather the runit() function

Comment: ok, now i could manage to get it work, with the callback of the animate function, it didnt work at the beginnen, because firebug killed the browser for any reason.

Answer (score 1):

ok i found a clean solution with jquery-timers[demo of the code below](http://www.irengba.com/codewell/loop.html)

$(document).ready(function(){

```
      $("#ball_holder").everyTime(3000, function(){                      
         $("#ball_holder").animate({top:"184px"}, 400).animate({top:"0px"}, 370);   
      });
```

here the 3000 is the interval of the function in miliseconds.Hope this helps

Comment: hm did you try it on the live example? because this does not work out for me